# Создание объектов класса с++

Tags: c++

Предположим, существует некоторый класс `foo` с конструктором по умолчанию. В main() происходит его создание.
Объясните, пожалуйста, разницу между :
`foo new_foo` и `foo new_foo()`

Comment: `foo new_foo()` не является созданием объекта класса вообще. Что оно делает в вопросе, озаглавленном "Создание объектов класса"?

Comment: И что значит "с конструктором по умолчанию"?

Comment: Вероятно имелось в виду `foo f = new foo();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это одна из самых вкусных кочек C++:

- `Foo new_foo;` — создаёт объект класса `Foo` конструктором по умолчанию
- `Foo new_foo();` — объявляет функцию `new_foo`, возвращающую объект класса Foo

Comment: Ответ вводит в заблуждение. `Foo new_foo{};` выполняет value-initialization, которая совсем не обязательно использует конструктор.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо за замечание — убрал — рассуждать на тему разницы *value-initialization* и *default-initialization* в этом вопросе будет не уместно... да и я не готов...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то если есть

```
class foo {..};

int main()
{
    foo new_foo();

    ...
}
```

то тут `foo new_foo();` - *объявление функции* `new_foo`, возвращающей объект типа `foo`...